# .NET - Print stack trace with variables

Tags: .net, reflection, exception, error-handling

To improve application error handling I would like to log exceptions stack traces and variables values of each stack level. I've searched for Reflection but couldn't find anything. How can I see the variables?

Answer (score 3):

Without using additional tools (such as creating memory dump, or using profiling API) you can't do it. While you can use [LocalVariableInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.localvariableinfo.aspx) class to list local variables, in order to display the values, you'd need to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

System.Environment.StackTrace property should write the Stack trace of the current managed stack. To get the variables, refer to [Get list of local objects/variables during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571085/get-list-of-local-objects-variables-during-runtime)